# Android Scrollview not scrolling (contains LinearLayout which enfolds a constraintLayout)

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview, android-linearlayout

Hej,

I am having my main activity layout in my android application, which contains a scollview. It's direct child is a linearlayout, which in turn holds a constraintlayout (it has constraint guidelines for it's layout elements).

I have not been able to set the views properly in order for the scrollview to be scrollable.
here is the xml code:

```
   <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_cvd_title_form">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainActivityLinLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainActiConLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/MidnightBlue"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

I have tried different approaches on the layout_width and height constraints for the layouts, but to no success. The scrollview contains only one direct child, the linear layout.

The constraintlayout that holds most of the elements uses guidelines to sort out the diffferent views and i would like it to remain as such, though i am sure that they are other options also to re-desing it (for example as part of the enfolding linear layout).

Answer (score 0):

You need to just correct your width and height both of the nested scrollview from 0 to match_parent

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/include_cvd_title_form">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainActivityLinLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainActiConLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/MidnightBlue"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

After this correction your code works fine ):